# Using docker volume with a NFS partition

Tags: nfs, docker, lxc

I have a NFS partition on the host, if add it to a container with

```
docker run -i -t -v /srv/nfs4/dir:/mnt ubuntu
```

/mnt will contain the shared data, but doesn't it cause conflicts? Since it hasn't been mounted with nfs-client?

Answer (score 4):

Docker [uses bind mounts](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/volumes.go#L37) to share host directories with containers. Docker handles namespace permission so that the container can access the mount. Otherwise from the host's perspective, the bind mounted NFS share is just being accessed by another process. It's safe to bind mount an NFS share elsewhere on the filesystem. Using it from within a Docker container is no different.

Answer (score 1):

As of Docker 1.7+ you can use a Volume Plugin. See the [Docker Volume Plugin](https://docs.docker.com/extend/plugins/) section for details.

As far as NFS goes you can use the [Docker Netshare](https://github.com/gondor/docker-volume-netshare) plugin which handles mounding NFS, CIFS and AWS EFS file systems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to share /srv/nfs4/ in your default docker machine. Go to virtualbox > default (or boot2docker) > settings > Shared Folder